# 2 aligned integrals

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I want the first two integrals to be aligned

```
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \int_{1}^{\infty}\underbrace{\ln(t-1) t^{\alpha-\gamma} 
    (1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (z-t)^{-\alpha}}_{top} \,dt\\
    +\underbrace{\int_{\infty}^{1}\underbrace{\ln(t-1) t^{\alpha-\gamma} 
    (1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (z-t)^{-\alpha}}_{bottom}\,dt}_{
    =-(1+2\pi i) \int_{1}^{\infty}\underbrace{\ln(t-1) t^{\alpha-\gamma} 
    (1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (z-t)^{-\alpha}}_{top}\,dt}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: I would use the `align` environment and then just write `&` where I want the aligns

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Except this appears to be a single equation, and with `align` each line is numbered by default. Also, the second `\int` is inside the argument to `\underbrace`.

Comment: Can you not put an `align*` inside the equation and then use `&\!\underbrace{\int ...`@TorbjørnT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to place the argument of the outermost `\underbrace` statement in a `\mathclap` directive. (`\mathclap` is a macro provided by the `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package.) The absence of alignment points means that the first two rows will both be right-aligned, in which case the presence of the `\underbrace`s won't matter.

For symmetry reasons, I would use `\overbrace`, not `\underbrace`, in the first row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \int_{1}^{\infty}\overbrace{\ln(t-1) t^{\alpha-\gamma} (1-t)^{\gamma-
    \beta-1} (z-t)^{-\alpha}}^{\text{top}} \,dt\\
    +\underbrace{\int_{\infty}^{1}\underbrace{\ln(t-1) t^{\alpha-\gamma}
    (1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (z-t)^{-\alpha}}_{\text{bottom}}\,dt}_%
    {\mathclap{ \displaystyle -(1+2\pi i)
    \int_{1}^{\infty}\underbrace{\ln(t-1) t^{\alpha-\gamma}
    (1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (z-t)^{-\alpha}}_{\text{top}}\,dt}}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```